# Exact String Match Python

Tags: python, string, match

The first line of code is supposed to find `string` A180, and shift down 9 rows and grab that value. My problem is, is that I also have A180X inside this file, so It's not grabbing the correct information because its also finding A180X.

The second Line I figured if I used `==String` it would find the exact match and it does. My problem is, is when I add `shift(9)` I get an error `'str' object has no attribute 'shift'`. Does anyone know how I can find the exact match but still use shift?

```
N2=NewFile2[NewFile2['FindString'].str.match(String,na=False).shift(9).fillna(False)]
    
N3=NewFile2[NewFile2['FindString']==(String).shift(9).fillna(False)]
```